# ViewPager loading the same background images for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Good day all, i have a slight issue i can't seem to get my head around it. i have a ViewPager of 3 fragments and this ViewPager is contained in a FrameLayout. What i am trying to do is that for every fragment, the background image of the FrameLayout Changes.

my FragmentActivity is:

```
pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

and in my MyPagerAdapter, i instantiate the fragments in the getItem() method:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
    return MyFragment.newInstance(position);

}
```

Now i can setup the values for the Views in the fragment correctly using the position

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int position){  //Add arraylist of hashmaps to populate it here.
        MyFragment my_fragment = new MyFragment();

        Bundle bundle = my_fragment.getArguments();
         if(bundle == null){
             bundle = new Bundle();
         }
         bundle.putInt(FRAGMENT_POSITION, position);

         my_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return my_fragment;
    }




  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if(args != null){
            position = args.getInt(FRAGMENT_POSITION);
        }

      //do other operations and Methods on views based on position.
```

and then at somepoint, i call a method  `((MyFragmentActivity)getActivity()).setLayoutBackground(resId) which sets the Background of the FrameLayout in the container Activity. My trouble is that, i can't seem to differentiate  which fragment is being called due to the nature that ViewPagers Load all the fragments together and I keep getting the same background for all the fragments in the ViewPager.

In MyFragmentActivity, i tried changing it in the PageChangeListener but no luck, i noticed that i am passing the same value all the time and so keep getting the same thing.

```
public void setLayoutBackground(int resId){

        layoutResId = resId;

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                app.setBackground(layout, layoutResId)
                //Log.d(TAG, "i am resId" + layoutResId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

What i need to do is pass the Position of the Fragment to the FragmentActivity so that it will load the correct Background but can't seem to figure it out. (The background drawable to load is based on a logic, so i can't define it from the start)Any Ideas how i could go about this or what i could be doing wrong because it has dealt with my weekend so far.. :) Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In `newInstance` there's no need to get the arguments and check if they're null.  They always will be on a new instance of the Fragment, so just start with a `new Bundle()` and cut out some boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of letting the Fragment set the layout background directly, have an `HashMap<Integer, Integer> fragmentBackgrounds;` field variable in the Activity and replace the method call to `((MyFragmentActivity)getActivity()).setLayoutBackground(resId)` with `((MyFragmentActivity)getActivity()).setFragmentBackground(position, resId)` where the Activity then puts the resId into the `fragmentBackgrounds` map with a key representing the position and the value representing the resId.  In the `onPageSelected()` method of the PageChangeListener, use the position it gives you to look up the resource in your map that that Fragment would like and set the layout background at that time (unless the key doesn't exist or the value is null or 0 of course).

You should also consider not calling the setFragmentBackground in the way that you are, because that assumes that the hosting Activity will always be an instance of `MyFragmentActivity` and instead you should define an interface with the `setFragmentBackground` method and make the Activity implement that interface.  Then, in the Fragment, override `onAttach`, check that the Activity that the Fragment is being attached to implements the interface with `instanceof` and assign the Activity to a field variable in the Fragment called `listener`.  In `onDetach()` set the listener to null and always check if the listener is null before calling any methods on it.

Comment: SDJMcHattie, great suggestion!.. will try that, am so brain dead this weekend.. :)  By the way, i am setting the background from the application class but you have a very valid point! Thanks once again